# MVC Huge Model Poor Performance

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC 3 and one of my views is binding to a rather large model. The actual model has over 130 properties (all these are used in the view). Every time when I postback the view it is extremely slow, it takes ages until hits the server side. Is this cause by the fact that I have client validation enabled?

Comment: How do you know it "takes ages until hits the server side"? What's it doing during that time? Did you check with a JS debugger? Is it just the submission of the HTML form to the controller that's slow, or the other way around as well? What does the HTML form look like? And how long is "forever"? ½ second? ½ minute?

Comment: Apply brute force and ignorance, if you disable client validation does it go significantly faster?

Comment: Murph, you are correct. When I have disabled client side validation everything goes smoothly.

Comment: You are asking users to fill forms with 130 fields? That's insane. If I see a form with that many fields the first key combination I would use on my keyboard is Ctrl+W (closes the current browser tab) and try to forget as fast as possible my visit on your web site. Even the most bureaucratic institutions don't ask you to fill that many data.

Comment: @Darin Totally agreed - possibility of having a client never come back again is directly proportional to the number of fields to fill;) I guess lots of those properties are not directly mapped to input fields, but still it looks bloated. On the other hand - I could imagine scenarios (mostly intranet), where there simply are lots of parameters to enter (and client prefers single form over wizard-like interface)...

Comment: There is no point to move away from the subject. This is not a public application, it is intranet based and these are the client requirements. Company employers have to fill that form with over 130 fields.

Comment: Try telling them they need to break the form down into several wizard steps...

Comment: Try the miniprofiler (http://miniprofiler.com/) and see where the time is going!

Comment: Someone will actually be filling 130 fields? Talk about bad jobs.

Answer (score 1):

*What do you mean by "hits server side"?*

It looks like a problem with model processing, not the problem with the framework. It really doesn't matter if your model has 5 or 130 properties - that shouldn't be user-noticeable at all.
Double-check your model processing code for long-running operations. If the model object is that big I'm pretty sure there are ones somewhere.

Also, I'd advise checking the client-server communication for any problems (javascript, heavy forms and so on). Built-in tools in IE9/Chrome and Fiddler are enough to track those kinds of issues.

Comment: There is no heavy processing in the model or with the model. By "hit the server side" I mean until the MVC executes the action. In my case the form is as heavy as the model is.

Comment: In addition to client-side validation (ending with really heavy JS...), pointed in comments to the main post - model binding can also possibly add a slight delay, although I'm not sure if that'd be also noticeable?

Comment: with client side validation disable is moving much faster. You are correct, the model binding is a little slower but I was expecting this to happen.